# Installation of Pytorch GPU Windows

Tags: python3, anaconda, python3.2

I was trying to install pytorch gpu(Windows) using the command: conda install -c anaconda pytorch-gpu.

But it is throwing the following error----
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

Comment: Just an FYI, according to [these PyTorch notes for Windows](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/windows.html), PyTorch doesn’t work on 32-bit systems. So you may need to ensure you are using 64-bit versions of Windows and Python.

Comment: What steps have you taken to research the possible cause of the error?